# Decompress all gz files in a tree

Tags: linux, shell, gzip

I am working on an Ubuntu 14 server.

Trying to create a `tar.gz` backup of my website, I accidentally gzipped every individual file in my `/var/www/` directory, recursively. Now the whole tree consists of `*.gz` files.

How can I restore them?

Answer (score 0):

Using `gunzip -r *` did the work.

Comment: Are you sure? Not decompressed for me.